# Integral $\int\frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the integral

$$\int\frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}dt$$

My Try:
Use Long division first and we got
$$\int 1+ \frac{128}{t^2-64}dt=\int 1 dt+ \int\frac{128}{t^2-64}dt$$ 
$$= \int 1 dt+ \int\frac{128}{(t-8)(t-8)}dt$$

And then use the [image: Integral Table]

Number $26$. $a=8 b=-8$

So we got

$$t+128\left(\frac{1}{16}\ln|t-8|-\ln|t+8|\right)+c$$

But it is not right. What is wrong?

Comment: $\frac{1}{z(z-2)}=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z})$

Comment: For 2, just use #26 with $a = 0$ and $b = 2$.

Comment: yes, you are right...

Comment: For number 1, the fraction $1/16$ goes on the outside of both logs, so the intermediate integral should be $\frac{1}{16}(\ln|t-8|-\ln|t+8|)$, not $\frac{1}{16}\ln|t-8|-\ln|t+8|$. Now if you do that your answer should simplify a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your final step you mixed up the brackets, it should be:

So we got
$$t+128\cdot\frac{1}{16}\bigg(\mathrm{ln}|t-8|-\mathrm{ln}|t+8|\bigg)=t+8\,\mathrm{ln}|t-8|-8\,\mathrm{ln}|t+8|$$
As [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2%2B64%29%2F%28x%5E2-64%29) confirms.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int{\frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}dt}=\int{\frac{t^2+8^2+2*8*t-2*8*t}{t^2-64}dt+c}$$
using the method used in quadratic equation above.
$$=\int{\frac{(t+8)^2-16t}{t^2-64}dt+c}=\int{\frac{t+8}{t-8}dt+\int{\frac{16t}{t^2-64}dt}}$$
$$=\int{\frac{t+8-8+8}{t-8}dt-8\int{\frac{2t}{t^2-64}dt}}$$
$$=\int{1+\frac{16}{t-8}dt}-8\ln{t^2-64}$$
$$=t+16*\ln{(t-8)}-8\ln{(t^2-64)+c}$$
This is the final integral

Comment: There should be $16$ in front of $\ln(t-8)$ (and maybe one could simplify the logarithms into one).

Comment: @mickep Thanks man it was an error

Answer (score 0):

First divide $t^2 + 64$ by $t^2 - 64$ to get

$$\frac{t^2 + 64}{t^2 - 64} = 1 + \frac{128}{t^2 - 64}$$

Then do a partial fraction decomposition:

$$\frac{128}{t^2 - 65} = \frac{A}{t + 8} + \frac{B}{t - 8}$$
$$128 = A(t - 8) + B(t+8)$$

Plugging in $t = -8$ to get $128 = -16~A \implies A = -8$.

Plugging in $t = 8$ to get $128 = 16~B \implies B = 8$.

So

$$\frac{t^2 + 64}{t^2 - 64} = 1 + \frac{128}{t^2 - 64} = 1 + \frac{-8}{t + 8} + \frac{8}{t - 8}$$

Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}dt$$
Note: 
$$\frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}=\left(\frac{t^2+64-\left(t^2-64\right)}{t^2-64}+1\right)$$
Then Apply Integral Substitution: $\color{green}{t=8u\quad \:dt=8du}$
$$=\int \frac{8\left(u^2+1\right)}{u^2-1}du=8\int \frac{u^2+1}{u^2-1}du$$
Note Again:$$\frac{u^2+1}{u^2-1}=\left(\frac{u^2+1-\left(u^2-1\right)}{u^2-1}+1\right)$$
$$=8\int \left(\frac{u^2+1-\left(u^2-1\right)}{u^2-1}+1\right)du=8\int \frac{2}{u^2-1}+1du$$
Apply the Sum Rule:
$$=8\left(\int \frac{2}{u^2-1}du+\int \:1du\right)=8\left(-2arctanh \left(u\right)+u\right)$$
So
$$\int \frac{t^2+64}{t^2-64}dt=\color{red}{8\left(\frac{t}{8}-2arctanh \left(\frac{t}{8}\right)\right)+C}$$